# Where value from column is in list

Tags: r

I have what I think is a pretty simple task, but cannot figure out how to do it in R.

Here is my data frame.

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 
    6, 6, 6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12)
type <- c('A', 'B', 'K',
          'A', 'B',
          'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
          'B', 'D', 'F',
          'A', 'G',
          'C', 'B', 'G',
          'B',
          'B',
          'B',
          'B',
          'B',
          'B')


    df <- data.frame(id, type)
```

I want to accomplish two things:

1. Pull the two most frequent occurences of `type` into a list
2. Use that list to subset the original dataframe.

So, I will pull any row that has A or B in it, then pull those ids and get all observations for those ids.  Does that make sense?

UPDATE:

Based on Matt's answer below, I was able to get this to work, but it's still not ideal...there has to be a better way, right?

```
vec <- df %>%
  count(type, sort = TRUE)

vec <- head(vec, 2)

vecx <- as.list(unique(as.character(vec$type)))

df3 <- df %>% 
  filter(type %in% vecx)
```

Comment: Simple suggestion (if I understand what you're trying to do -- I'm not sure I do): maybe `table()` or `dplyr::arrage()` to see what are the most frequent cases you want (let's say C & D here) and then `dplyr::filter(type == "C" | type == "D")`?

Comment: i don't want to hard code it. so i want it to dynamically filter the top two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 2

df <- merge(as.data.frame(head(count(df, type, sort = TRUE), n)), df)[,c("id","type")]
```

Comment: Hey Matt-- I realized that this is only taking the most frequent value (in this case it works because the top two are tied at 4 occurences).  How can i generalize to get top n?

Comment: This is still not right.  I couldn't figure out what was wrong, but realized that since this is sorting by decreasing ALPHA, the counts are not right.  I updated the data set to highlight the issue.  Now that B has more than 9 obs, it is not recognized as the most frequent value.

Comment: I think this latest update should work the way you need it to.

Comment: Yes!  I knew there had to be a more elegant way than what I was doing.  Thanks.